# Rails API : how to allow one single url to call my API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

My environment is a Rails 7 API + React frontend.

The issue is that we need to call the API from the frontend only and prevent others urls to make any requests. I tried to configure this with the gem rack-cors and its file `config/initializers/cors.rb` as this (allowing only localhost:3001) :

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins 'http://localhost:3001'
  
      resource '*',
               headers: :any,
               methods: %i[get post put patch delete options head],
               expose: %w[Authorization Uid]
    end
  end
```

The problem is that a POST request made with POSTMAN is not blocked.

What did I miss ?

Thanks.

Julien

Comment: Have you restarted Rails since adding the localhost configuration?

Comment: Yes I restarted the rail server.

Comment: Are you passing an `Origin:` header via Postman? Per the docs it's required to trigger a CORS response. https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors#testing-postman-andor-curl

Comment: I did not pass any `Origin:` header. What is it supposed to be set there, an IP address ?

Comment: To your question, if you pass something other than `http://localhost:3001` as the origin, it should be blocked by this configuration.

Comment: Actually, it worked for the requests I tried (they are blocked).
But the same requests made with POSTMAN are not blocked.

Comment: When sending the Postman requests, are you including the `Origin: ` header?

Comment: Yes I am including ``Origin: http://localhost:3001`` which is the allowed URL. And when I am including ``Origin: http://localhost:3002``, it's not blocked.
And here is ``cors.rb`` setting : ``origins 'http://localhost:3001'``

Comment: Do you think that this config file is being run? I noticed that it isn't located in `config/initializers/` (question mentions `config/cors.rb`), which is where I'd expect it to be.

Comment: It is my mistake, I just corrected the question. The file is in `config/initializers/cors.rb` .

Comment: I think the path forward is: confirm that this initializer is being run, confirm that Postman is sending an `Origin:` header that should blocked. If both are yes, open an issue with rack-cors.

Comment: Okay, that's what I am gonna do. Thanks a lot !